# External USB disk only shows up as core storage logical volume via diskutil list, can't erase or otherwise manipulate

Tags: partition, external-disk, error, disk-format

My drive got hosed along the way. (Possibly related, more frequent kernel panics). My solution is to zap, do a backup, clean install OS and it'll all be copacetic.

Trouble is, the external will only show up as core storage logical volume.

Setup: MacOS Catalina, Intel MBPro 13" 2020, External USB enclosure for WD Red 3.5" drive (same results in two enclosures), booted from internal drive, except for a few recent kernel panics, Mac seems to be operating normally. External drive used primarily for Time Machine, and some media storage.

diskutil list output:

```
    /dev/disk3 (external, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Going Places           +4.0 TB     disk3
                                 Logical Volume on 
                                 AEF92868-12E0-45A8-A7D4-1F4F83B54D00
                                 Unencrypted
```

gpt show says "resource busy," diskutil unmount produces "success" but no change in gpt show.

diskutil error is:

```
Unable to begin erase operation: Placing a partition map on a Core Storage logical volume is not supported (-69671)
```

I've surrendered the data to the void, but if the drive hardware is OK figured I could use it, at least to accomplish a clean install and get the documents back easily. I don't rely on time machine for stability, I use ARQ for safety and time machine for convenience. But bringing back everything from ARQ is kinda slow.

Any thoughts?

Edit: `diskutil list` output is now different (full output per @Jean_JD)

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         500.0 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +500.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            11.3 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     347.0 GB   disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Preboot                 82.4 MB    disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume Recovery                529.0 MB   disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume VM                      3.2 GB     disk1s5

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *4.0 TB     disk2
   1:                       0xEE                         4.0 TB     disk2s1
```

Update 2: Being a curious sort, I switched it back into the original enclosure. It showed up in Disk Utility, but selecting it gives me the bbod. This points to failing hardware somewhere to me. Luckily for my sake, I followed @Tetsujin request once more before selection:

`diskutil cs list`

```
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 13D26D80-5923-4CE9-9431-EAFDBAB166B5
    =========================================================
    Name:         Untitled
    Status:       Online
    Size:         4000409505792 B (4.0 TB)
    Free Space:   16564224 B (16.6 MB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 8222A583-144C-48AA-8AD6-DCB58C56C61A
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk2s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     4000409505792 B (4.0 TB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family D94A8545-389E-4A14-AC64-E6118D904C2C
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Type:         AES-XTS
        Encryption Status:       Unlocked
        Conversion Status:       Converting (backward)
        Reversion State:         Decrypting
        High Level Queries:      Not Fully Secure
        |                        Has Visible Users
        |                        Has Volume Key
        |
        +-> Logical Volume AEF92868-12E0-45A8-A7D4-1F4F83B54D00
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk3
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          4000040615936 B (4.0 TB)
            Conversion Progress:   1%
            Revertible:            No
            LV Name:               Going Places
            Volume Name:           Going Places
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
```

Comment: There are a lot of holes in this explanation. First, what OS? What Mac? CoreStorage is a thing of the past, no longer used. 2. Why are you using the external? What happened to the internal? What are you booted from... Recovery, Internet recovery, another external/internal? Why are you showing us a virtual drive info, rather than the physical info? Why are you trying to erase from Terminal rather than Disk Utility?

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for helping me complete my question, I have updated to address your issues. Summarily: time machine, internal is fine, booted normally, what I pasted is all diskutil list reports, disk utility doesn't show the drive at all.

Comment: Can you add to your initial question the entire results of terminal command : `diskutil list`?

Comment: Actually, as it's still on Catalina, we need the results of `diskutil cs list`

Comment: @Tetsujin "No Corestorage logical volume groups found"

Comment: After your latest edit, I'm going to take a punt that the two enclosures are mapping the sector sizes differently. Some external enclosures map virtual sector sizes [which is something to not upset old Windows PCs as far as I can tell.] This means if you change enclosures, the mapping no longer matches & the drive becomes, to all intents & purposes 'unreadable'. This would provide an explanation as to why it can show up as CoreStorage AND FDisk.